# NDVI error over vegetated surfaces and water

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I performed an NDVI analysis using Qgis 2.18 'Las Palmas' of an area of Landsat 7 (wrs_path 168, wrs_row 061),date 2007-12-25 and Landsat 8 (same path and row) date 2017-12-28.  I clipped both images to x max and x min (36.59588, 36.79113)and y max and y min (-1.29795 and -1.46917).thereafter i used raster calculator to perform the NDVI formula -NDVI=(NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED)for each image,to generate two image outputs,one for 2007 and the other for 2017.

The issue is that the NDVI values for vegetation of the 2017 output image are too low, with negative even and shockingly water has a positive value of +1, which is a dam located at latlong (-1.44070, 36.69519).  2007 values were sensible but why this weird values in 2017?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the individual bands that are used to compute NDVI in that image?

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS in question titles. Doing so is a downvote magnet because of reduced legibility. Even though you've been here a while, you stll haven't taken the [Tour]. Please be sure to specify the exact GIS software in use within the body of the question, and to specify the exact inputs and procedure that led to the problem.

Comment: Yes I checked all individual bands of each image.I used the NIR band5 and Red band 4 for the 2017 Landsat 8 image and NIR band 4 and Red band 3 for the 2007  Landsat 7 image.plus I ve reedited my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have provided enough details, I made several tests on Landsat 8 data to better understand the situation (I don't mean to insult you).

(1) NDVI from Landsat 8 bands `(B5 - B4) / (B5 + B4)`

[image]

(2) If Landsat 7 and 8 bands were mixed up... `(B4 - B3) / (B4 + B3)`

[image]

(3) For some reason, this one (below) looks similar to your case... `(B3 - B5) / (B3 + B5)` (cf. *Open Water Index* by Green and NIR).

[image]

So, as [Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) has commented, you might as well check the input bands again.

Comment: The problem still remains.I rechecked my input bands and they are all correct. My stacked image is named 'clippedtiff'. So my band 5 was clippedtiff@5 and my band 4 was clippedtiff@4 and I performed the NDVI formula of NDVI=(NIR-RED)/(NIR +RED). So in my case in the raster calculator expression box it was-- (clippedtiff@5-clippedtiff@4)/(clippedtiff@5+clippedtiff@4) and the output was the same in the above 2017 img. In the SCP plugin under bandset it was set to Landsat 8 quickwavelength. The image info is LC08_L1TP_168061_20171228_20180103_01_T1, wrs_path 168, wrs_row 061 for 28-12-2007.

Comment: @SamuelGachuhi I think you are doing correctly. Only difference I had in my workflow was that I used each band as separate files (i.e. single-band raster).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your innovative comment.I now have a reasonable NDVI Image of 2017.  Click here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290956/ndvi-error-over-vegetated-surfaces-and-water/291088?noredirect=1#comment467913_291088

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check NDVi results for your scene using [this satellite image browser](https://eos.com/landviewer/?s=Landsat8&lat=-1.14868&lng=36.98822&z=10&id=LC08_L1TP_168061_20171228_20180103_01_T1&b=NIR,Red&expression=(NIR-Red)%2F(NIR%2BRed)&anti&pansharpening) or [this one](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/). They calculate NDVI as custom index with custom parameters but you can use menu to adjust it to your liking. I tried to run analysis with your palette, classes, levels etc. and [here's](https://eos.com/landviewer/?s=Landsat8&lat=-1.11573&lng=37.28622&z=10&id=LC08_L1TP_168061_20171228_20180103_01_T1&b=NIR,Red&colormap=32c262a96114f7fa956ea6debafcbd1d&expression=(B5-B4)%2F(B5%2BB4)&levels=-0.502,1&cb=true&anti&pansharpening) what I got.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The comment from kazuhito did the work,and therefore the NDVI output was more reasonable. I calculated the NDVI using single individual bands as he suggested.